# Problema ao receber dados do banco de dados com if/else

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, if, tabela-html

Galera estou com um problema no meu php, eu quero selecionar o nome das pessoas de acordo com um código e para isso fiz um IF, porém o código que deve pegar os valores do banco de dados e imprimir na página está repetindo um comando antes de imprimir o valor seguinte. Agradeço quem puder me ajudar.

Código:

PHP - Consulta:

```
<?php include("config.php");
    $consulta1 = $MySQLi -> query("SELECT * FROM TB_HOSPITAIS");
    $consulta2 = $MySQLi -> query("SELECT * FROM TB_MEDICOS 
      join TB_PLANTOES on MED_PLANT_CODIGO = PLANT_CODIGO
      join TB_HORARIOS on PLANT_HOR_CODIGO = HOR_CODIGO");
?>
```

Tabela - Mostrando os valores:

```
<table class="table table-striped" border="2" align="center text-center">
              <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Medico(a)</th>
                <th scope="col">Horário</th>
              </tr>
              <?php while($resultado2 = $consulta2 -> fetch_assoc()) {?>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">Domingo</th>
                  <td> 
                    <?php if ($resultado2['MED_PLANT_CODIGO'] == 1)
                      echo $resultado2['MED_NOME']; ?> 
                  </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $resultado2['HOR_HORARIO']; ?> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row">Segunda</th>
                  <td> 
                    <?php if ($resultado2['MED_PLANT_CODIGO'] == 2)
                      echo $resultado2['MED_NOME']; ?> 
                  </td>
                  <td> <?php echo $resultado2['HOR_HORARIO']; ?> </td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>          
            </table>
```

Config.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $endereco = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $banco = "DB_SCH";

    $MySQLi = new mysqli($endereco, $usuario, $senha, $banco, 3306);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        die(mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
    mysqli_set_charset($MySQLi,"utf8");

    function br_us($data) {
        $data = implode("-",array_reverse(explode("/",$data)));
        return $data;
    }
    function us_br($data) {
        $data = implode("/",array_reverse(explode("-",$data)));
        return $data;
    }
?>
```

Na tabela ao invés de imprimir o nome do médico do plantão 1 no domingo e depois o nome do médico que está no plantão 2 na segunda, ele primeiro imprime a segunda-feira como vazio, gera uma nova tabela e imprime o valor da segunda e deixa o domingo vazio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me parece existir 2 problemas na sua lógica

1. Você espera que os dados venham ordenados iniciando pelo domingo, mas não os ordena
2. Cada loop imprime todos os dias

Altere a sua query para

```php
$consulta2 = $MySQLi -> query("SELECT * FROM TB_MEDICOS 
  join TB_PLANTOES on MED_PLANT_CODIGO = PLANT_CODIGO
  join TB_HORARIOS on PLANT_HOR_CODIGO = HOR_CODIGO
  ORDER BY MED_PLANT_CODIGO ASC");
```

E a sua lógica no loop para

```php
<?php while($resultado2 = $consulta2 -> fetch_assoc()) {?>
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><IMPRIMIR DIA></th>
  <td><?php echo $resultado2['MED_NOME']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $resultado2['HOR_HORARIO']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

No lugar de ter uma lógica de `IF`s como vc está fazendo, seria melhor ter algo como

```php
$dias = array("1" => "Domingo", "2" => "Segunda");
```

E no seu loop faria

```php
<?php echo $dias[$resultado2['MED_PLANT_CODIGO']]; ?>
```

Juntando as peças:

```php
<?php
$dias = array("1" => "Domingo","1" => "Segunda");
while($resultado2 = $consulta2 -> fetch_assoc()):
?>
<tr>
  <th scope="row"><?php echo $dias[$resultado2['MED_PLANT_CODIGO']]; ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $resultado2['MED_NOME']; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $resultado2['HOR_HORARIO']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endif; ?>
```

PS: Essa lógica resolve os problemas apresentados. Entretanto pode haver outros problemas, como a query retornar mais de um resultado por dia. Neste caso seriam listados todos os domingos, em seguidas as segundas, ...

Comment: Você conseguiria me explicar como faço pra deixar os dias da semana fixos na <td> e aí o código que correspondesse a esse dia, apareceria lá? Porque minha ideia era sexta, sábado e domingo receber 2 nomes na mesma <td> e está sendo criada uma nova <td> para o segundo nome.

Comment: @eu.eu não consegui entender bem o que vc quer fazer, mas me parece que seria uma nova pergunta. também seria importante adicionar exemplos de registros da base de dados, o que espera que seja retornado pela query e o que/como deverá ser apresentado.

Answer (score -3):

@tvdias, realmente aconteceu como você falou, ele listou todos os domingos e por último todas as segundas, pra isso eu coloquei uma consulta por . Veja:

```
<?php while($resultado2 = $consulta2 -> fetch_assoc()) {?>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row"><?php echo $dias[$resultado2['MED_PLANT_CODIGO']]; ?></th>
                  <td><?php echo $resultado2['MED_NOME']; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo $resultado2['HOR_HORARIO']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php while($resultado3 = $consulta2 -> fetch_assoc()) {?>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="row"><?php echo $dias[$resultado3['MED_PLANT_CODIGO']]; ?></th>
                    <td><?php echo $resultado3['MED_NOME']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $resultado3['HOR_HORARIO']; ?></td>
                </tr>
              <?php } ?>
```